# How to delete string from specified symbol till the end with SED?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a problem with SED. I want to remove string from the ")" symbol till the end of line.

```
@"String1", @"Lobby", @"label in lobby");
@"Game Type", @"MainMenu", @"Game type selection in lobby") selection:gameTypeLabel];
```

I tried to use such script:

```
sed -i "s!\(*$!oo!" tmp_used_strings2.txt
```

Can anyone help me with regexp? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I understand. What exactly should be the output?

Comment: What on earth do you think that command means???

Comment: Maybe you have to place `-i` switch just before file name: `sed [-e] "sedscript" -i "/path/file"`

Comment: In many shell, `$!` is a variable (last bg job pid). use quotes `'` instead of double quote `"` for your sed script.

Comment: Regex `\/*$` stand for  *0 or more `(` at end of line*, so this will match each lines, but drop all `(` at end of each lines, if there are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have way too much stuff there.  Try this one:

```
sed 's/).*//' tmp_used_strings2.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

As @CarlNorum showed this is trivial in sed, but it's actually the job `cut` was invented to do:

```
cut -d')' -f1
```

Comment: except, I think the OP wants to be left with the part *before* the `)`, so it should probably be `cut -d')' -f1`...